# How to make this auto-sliding effect on iOS

Tags: iphone

I'm new on iPhone. Could you please tell me how to make an auto-sliding effect like this? Thanks.
Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rDBJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a UIPageControl, here is a link to a stackoverflow answer with a link to a UIPageControl Tutorial: [UIPageControl Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816144/uipagecontrol-help/1922110#1922110)

And using NSTimer to change page programmatically, here is a link to a stackoverflow answer explaining how to change pages programmatically: [Change page Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960177/problem-in-uipagecontrol/5960233#5960233)

To animate the page change, use UIViewAnimation methods: [UIView Animation sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126833/what-are-block-based-animation-methods-in-iphone-os-4-0/3316009#3316009)